# How can I prove self studied knowledge to a potential employer?

Tags: interviewing, resume, internship, work-experience

I am a second year business student who is looking for internships but I don't have a lot of work experience. However, I have completed various personal projects. Furthermore, I have gathered knowledge related to the field in which I want to enter and furthermore, have attended several courses on Coursera relating to the field which I want to enter.

> How would I go about proving this knowledge in an interview? How would I go about displaying this on my resume?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Coursera certificates? Show samples of your projects

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a portfolio with all your projects, if that's possible.

Try to get certificates from the courses you attend (I know most of the courses in Coursera do offer such).

Or write articles on the subject either in a personal blog or LinkedIn (or any other business oriented social platform) - that will show your level of expertise and understandings in this area.

Include those in your CV and your potential employer will have a good source to validate your skills and knowledge. And of course get yourself really prepared for a face-to-face discussion - this is always the easiest way to show *and prove* your good knowledge.

Comment: On your first point; In an interview setting, would I tell my interviewer that my portfolio is available online to look at? Also, how would I do this on a resume?

Comment: @gekkostate Designers have the luxury of bringing a tablet to show off during the interview, you probably don't. You could show your portfolio (along with your blog and everything else) under a "Personal Projects" heading. Or put the most interesting projects _from_ the portfolio under the same heading, and leave a URL to the rest if they're interested.

Comment: @gekkostate On the very interview you could bring a printed CV with link(s) to your portfolio or projects. There are nice web platforms, where one could store his portfolio (behance.net, about.me, etc), but I personally prefer to use LinkedIn, as it provides all necessary options to include my projects, skills and knowledge and... well, brag a little :)

One thing you should do for sure: add link to your LinkedIn account in your CV or cover letter **prior** to the interview. This way you'll give the employer a chance to research a little about you and be more prepared himself.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer and advice. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to find some kind of respectable test (which you'll probably have to pay to take). Or you might simply present examples of your best work.